# :after :before toggle wrapper opacity

Tags: css, toggle, wrapper, opacity

so im trying to make a button on my site that when hovered will make the content of the page have 0 opacity. this is my code

```
#wrapper{
box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
position:relative;
width:960px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
transition:opacity 1s;}
#wrapper:after{
width:100px;
height:100px;
cursor:;
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
content:'';
display:block;
left:-200px;
z-index:10000;
position:absolute;
top:-50px;
border-radius:150px;}
#wrapper :after :hover{
opacity:0;}
```

but it wont seem to work, anyone have any ideas or will it just not work?

Comment: on which browser it is not working?

Comment: You have no interest in using JavaScript to do this?

Comment: `cursor:;` try to insert a value here. And try also  `#wrapper:hover:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery:

```
$('.button-class').hover(function(){
    $('body').css({'opacity' : '0'});
}, function(){
    $('body').not(this).css({'opacity' : '1'});
});
```

Make sure you have a js file though

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#wrapper
{
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#wrapper:hover
{
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: yeah but wont that make the wrapper go invisible on hover, i want the wrapper to go invisible on the wrapper:after:hover otherwise wouldn't the page be inacessable

Answer (score 0):

Your css some wrong Correct to this

**Used to  this**  `#wrapper:hover:after`  This is write

**Not this** `#wrapper :after :hover`  This is wrong

```
    #wrapper:hover:after {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/gdTWx/2/)**

Comment: that fixed part of it but now when i hover over it the :after disappears but not the #wrapper (in firefox) and internet explored just displays the :after, no opacity change on hover

Comment: than you can used to jquery